# Simple explanation of the weak star topology?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

I have been trying to understand the weak star topology, but as is often the case the material online is quite hard to understand.

For a Banach space $X$ and the dual space $X^{*}$ could someone please explain what the weak star topology on $X^{*}$ is?

Comment: It's hard to see how to answer this. The explanation of what the weak* topology is would be the definition, but you've seen the definition...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There's more to explanations than just telling someone a definition...

Answer (score 0):

The weak star topology on $X^\ast$ is the subspace topology we inherit when we see $X^\ast$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^X$ (the set of all functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$) (assuming the reals as underlying field here). $\Bbb R^X$ has the usual product topology (i.e. the minimal topology that makes all all projections (or really evaluations here) continuous). That's really all there is to it.